# Haskell compiled program giving a segfault

Tags: haskell, segmentation-fault, ghc

Compiling with `cabal` and `GHC-Options: -dcore-lint -debug` a program and the running with `+RTS -DS`, I'm getting the following:

```
cap 0: initialised
goog-closure: internal error: ASSERTION FAILED: file rts/sm/Sanity.c, line 87

    (GHC version 7.6.3 for x86_64_unknown_linux)
    Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
Aborted
```

It's most probably the GC, adding some prints to bisect the offending instruction just move the failing point. I know I have to find a small reproducible test case. Right now it's 100% reproducible, but not quite small. I'm leaving this here for someone who can point me at an easier direction if possible. Additional info:

```
user@server:/home/user/$ ghc -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.1
Using binary package database: /home/user/.haskell/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
Using binary package database: /home/user/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
hiding package Cabal-1.16.0 to avoid conflict with later version Cabal-1.20.0.0
hiding package containers-0.5.0.0 to avoid conflict with later version containers-0.5.5.1
hiding package filepath-1.1.0.4 to avoid conflict with later version filepath-1.3.0.1
hiding package Cabal-1.18.1.3 to avoid conflict with later version Cabal-1.20.0.0
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.0.0-d5221a8c8a269b66ab9a07bdc23317dd
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.0.0-2f15426f5b53fe4c6490832f9b20d8d7
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.6.0.1-8aa5d403c45ea59dcd2c39f123e27d57
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.8.0.0-a3012803fde1dc362e555b35a1a78e6d
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

Comment: Can you try with ghc-7.8?  It's definitely a bug in the RTS, so maybe it's been fixed in a newer release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an error with ghc-7.6.3. ghc-7.8.3 no longer gives segfault. Thanks @john-l.